# how do I only get integer by using python if else conditional

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print 'enter a number'
s = raw_input()
s = float(s)
q = int(s)
if s == q:
    print 'it is an integer'
else:
    print 'it is not an integer'
```

When somebody enters a character, I would also like to have the message displayed "It is not  an integer". How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at what happens when somebody enters a character?

Answer (score 3):

You should [`try`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) it:

```
try:
    q = int(s)
    print 'it is an integer'
except ValueError:
    print 'it is not an integer'
```

The Python philosophy is *"it's better to ask for forgiveness than for permission"*, i.e. try to parse `s` as an int and catch any errors as opposed to checking if `s` is parseable as an int to begin with.

Note that you can also do the same thing with `float(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`try`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) block around where you cast to an integer and catch a [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError). That's the error thrown when the cast fails:

```
s = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    q = int(s)
except ValueError as e:
    print "{} is not an integer!".format(q)
```

Also, note you can include the prompt in the [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) call.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    q = int(s)
except ValueError:
    print 'It is not an integer.'
```